# Cannot call 'box.get_right' with argument 'id'='call '_controlBox' (void)'. An argument of 'void' type was used but a 'series box' is expected

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i have Pine script Question and i worked on it for many days and i cant solve it , please help me :

i have this code ,

```
//@version=5
//This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
indicator('Super OrderBlock / FVG / BoS Tools by makuchaku & eFe', overlay=true, max_boxes_count=500, max_lines_count=500 , max_labels_count=500)

plotOB = input.bool(defval=true, title='Plot OB', group='Order Blocks')
obBullColor = input.color(defval=color.new(color.green, 90), title='Bullish OB Color', inline='Set Custom Color', group='Order Blocks')
obBearColor = input.color(defval=color.new(color.red, 90), title='Bearish OB Color', inline='Set Custom Color', group='Order Blocks')
obBoxBorder = input.string(defval=line.style_solid, title='OB Box Border Style', options=[line.style_dashed, line.style_dotted, line.style_solid], group='Order Blocks', tooltip='To disable border, set Border Width below to 0')
obBorderTransparency = input.int(defval=80, title='OB Border Box Transparency', minval=0, maxval=100, group='Order Blocks')
obMaxBoxSet = input.int(defval=10, title='Maximum OB Box Displayed', minval=1, maxval=100, group='Order Blocks', tooltip='Minimum = 1, Maximum = 100')
filterMitOB = input.bool(defval=true, title='Custom Color Mitigated OB', group='Order Blocks')
mitOBColor = input.color(defval=color.new(color.yellow, 20), title='Mitigated OB Color', group='Order Blocks', inline='Set Custom Color Mit OB', tooltip='Set Transparency to 0 to make mitigated OB disappear')

plotLabelOB = input.bool(defval=true, title='Plot OB Label', inline='OB label', group='Label Options')
obLabelColor = input.color(defval=color.gray, title='Color', inline='OB label', group='Label Options')
obLabelSize = input.string(defval=size.tiny, title="Size", options=[size.huge, size.large, size.small, size.tiny, size.auto, size.normal], inline='OB label', group='Label Options')

//Box Types
var int _ob  = 1
var int _fvg = 2
var int _rjb = 3
var int _bos = 4

//Box Labels
var string _obLabel  = "OB"
var string _fvgLabel = "FVG"
var string _rjbLabel = "RJB"
var string _bosLabel = "BoS"
var string _plus     = "+"
var string _minus    = "-"
var string _empty    = ""

//Box Arrays
var box[] _bearBoxesOB  = array.new_box()
var box[] _bullBoxesOB  = array.new_box()

//Functions
isUp(index) =>
    close[index] > open[index]

isDown(index) =>
    close[index] < open[index]

isObUp(index) =>
    isDown(index + 1) and isUp(index) and close[index] > high[index + 1]

isObDown(index) =>
    isUp(index + 1) and isDown(index) and close[index] < low[index + 1]

isFvgUp(index) =>
    (low[index] > high[index + 2])

isFvgDown(index) =>
    (high[index] < low[index + 2])


//Function to Calculte Box Length
_controlBox(_boxes, _high, _low, _type) =>
    var box_right1 = 0
    var box_right2 = 0
    var box_right3 = 0
    if array.size(_boxes) > 0
        for i = array.size(_boxes) - 1 to 0 by 1
            _box = array.get(_boxes, i)
            _boxLow = box.get_bottom(_box)
            _boxHigh = box.get_top(_box)
            _boxRight = box.get_right(_box)
        
            if (_type == _ob) 
                if na or (bar_index == _boxRight and not((_high > _boxLow and _low < _boxLow) or (_high > _boxHigh and _low < _boxHigh)))
                    box.set_right(_box, bar_index + 1)
                else
                    if _type == _ob
                        box.set_bgcolor(_box, mitOBColor)
                        box.set_border_color(_box, mitOBColor)
////////////////// Pivots //////////////////// 

if isObUp(1) and plotOB
    _bullboxOB = box.new(left=bar_index - 2, top=high[2], right=bar_index, bottom=math.min(low[2], low[1]), border_color=color.new(obBullColor, obBorderTransparency), border_style=obBoxBorder, border_width=1, bgcolor=obBullColor, 
     text=plotLabelOB ? _obLabel  + _plus : _empty, text_halign=text.align_right, text_valign=text.align_bottom, text_size=obLabelSize, text_color=obLabelColor)
    if array.size(_bullBoxesOB) > obMaxBoxSet
        box.delete(array.shift(_bullBoxesOB))
    array.push(_bullBoxesOB, _bullboxOB)

//Bearish OB Box Plotting
if isObDown(1) and plotOB
    _bearboxOB = box.new(left=bar_index - 2, top=math.max(high[2], high[1]), right=bar_index, bottom=low[2], border_color=color.new(obBearColor, obBorderTransparency), border_style=obBoxBorder, border_width=1, bgcolor=obBearColor, 
     text=plotLabelOB ? _obLabel  + _minus : _empty, text_halign=text.align_right, text_valign=text.align_bottom, text_size=obLabelSize, text_color=obLabelColor)
    if array.size(_bearBoxesOB) > obMaxBoxSet
        box.delete(array.shift(_bearBoxesOB))
    array.push(_bearBoxesOB, _bearboxOB)

if plotOB
    _controlBox(_bearBoxesOB, high, low, _ob)
    _controlBox(_bullBoxesOB, high, low, _ob)

getBoxRight = box.get_right(_controlBox(_bearBoxesOB, high, low, _ob))
```

i want to plotshape or label on last candle that block closed . that i draw it white arrow down (Sticker) ..

please Help me ...

Error : Error at 99:29 Cannot call 'box.get_right' with argument 'id'='call '_controlBox' (void)'. An argument of 'void' type was used but a 'series box' is expected.

Answer (score 0):

`_controlBox()` is a function which returns nothing (`void`). And you are trying to use its return value in `box.get_right()` which will not work and what the compiler tells you.

You need to pass a `box` object. Both `_bearBoxesOB` and `_bullBoxesOB` are array of boxes. You can also not pass those arrays because you need to pass a single object.

You should write a function and iterate over your array. Find which `box` object that satisfies your condition and get its `right` argument.

Comment: i tried many times , but i cant do this , help me and try to write it